# How to generate summary from JSON data Using watson discovery news servies

Tags: python, json, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

How to generate summary like IBM from json using discovery news services with python

```
qopts = {'nested':'(enriched_text.entities)','filter':'(enriched_text.entities.type::Person)','term':'(enriched_text.entities.text,count:10)','filter':'(enriched_text.concepts.text:infosys)','filter':'(enriched_text.concepts.text:ceo)'}
my_query = discovery.query('system', 'news', qopts)  
print(json.dumps(my_query, indent=2))
```

This query is proper or not for find ceo of Infosys ? 
Output came in large json format the how I identify answer or create summary like top ten ceo or people.
How to generate summary from json using discovery news services with python. I fire query then output became large json format ..how to find proper summary from that json file my query is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two questions here.

1. In order to answer a question like "Who is the CEO of Infosys?" I would instead make use of the `natural_language_query` parameter as follows:

   ```
   qopts = {'natural_language_query':'Who is the CEO of Infosys?','count':'5'}
   response = discovery.query(environment_id='system',collection_id='news',query_options=qopts)
   print(json.dumps(response,indent=2))
   ```
2. In order to make use of aggregations, they must be specified in a single `aggregation` parameter combined with `filter` aggregations in the query options as follows:

   ```
   qopts = {'aggregation': 'nested(enriched_text.entities).filter(enriched_text.entities.type::Person).term(enriched_text.entities.text,count:10)', 'filter':'enriched_text.entities:(text:Infosys,type:Company)','count':'0'}
   response = discovery.query(environment_id='system',collection_id='news',query_options=qopts}
   print(json.dumps(response,indent=2))
   ```

Notice that aggregations are chained/combined with the `.` symbol.

Comment: you can also use a `return` parameter to limit the fields that are returned to make the JSON more manageable -> `qopts = {'return':'enriched_title'}`

Comment: 2 Option is best but sir how I am use this "return " parameter like ->qopts = {'return':'enriched_title'}

Comment: @AndrewTurgeon Please see the follow on question to your answer.

Comment: yes, you would combine it as another key in addition to your other keys. for example: `qopts = {'return':'enriched_title','aggregation': 'nested(enriched_text.entities).filter(enriched_text.entities.type::Person).term(enriched_text.entities.text,count:10)', 'filter':'enriched_text.entities:(text:Infosys,type:Company)','count':'0'}`